# Check only the checkbox if Yes button was clicked on bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

If I want to check a checkbox then, if "YES" button was clicked on bootstrap modal the checkbox must be check and remains uncheck if "NO" button was clicked.

Same on the other way, If want to uncheck a checkbox then, if "YES" button was clicked on bootstrap modal the checkbox must uncheck and remains check if "NO" button was clicked.

**HTML**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="" class="status">John Doe
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="" class="status" checked>James Doe
    </label>

  <!-- Activate -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="activate" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Activate?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-yes" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-no" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>           </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Deactivate -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="deactivate" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Deactivate?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-yes" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-no" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>           </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.status').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#activate').modal('show');
    } else {
        $('#deactivate').modal('show');
    }
});
```

**JSFIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/br86rjby/

Say something like this
http://jsfiddle.net/dfKEZ/

but only it should be a bootstrap modal

THANKS FOR HELPING !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the clicked checkbox and return `false` to prevent it from changing state. And then check or uncheck it based on what button was pressed in the dialog:

```js
var clickedCheckox;

$('.status').click(function(){
 clickedCheckbox = $(this);
  if(clickedCheckbox.is(':checked')) {
    $('#activate').modal('show');
  } else {
    $('#deactivate').modal('show');
  }

  return false;
});

$("#activateBtn").click(function() {
 clickedCheckbox.prop("checked", true);
});

$("#deactivateBtn").click(function() {
 clickedCheckbox.prop("checked", false);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxJohn" value="" class="status">John Doe
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxJames" value="" class="status" checked>James Doe
    </label>

  <!-- Activate -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="activate" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Activate?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button id="activateBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-yes" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-no" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>           </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Deactivate -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="deactivate" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Deactivate?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button id="deactivateBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-yes" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-no" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>           </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) if you don't want the checkbox to change its state on click

```
// variable will hold a checkbox:
var status_box = null;

$('.status').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // set which checkbox has been clicked:
  status_box = this;
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#activate').modal('show');
  } else {
    $('#deactivate').modal('show');
  }
});
```

Then register click event handler for buttons inside modal:

```
$('.btn-yes').click(function(){
    $(status_box).prop('checked', !status_box.checked);
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/br86rjby/3/)

---

Alternatively, you can get rid of the *`status_box`* variable by storing clicked checkbox in a [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-dataset) of the `'.btn-yes'` button:

```
$('.status').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.btn-yes').data('status_box', this);
  $(this.checked ? '#activate' : '#deactivate').modal('show');
});

$('.btn-yes').click(function(){
  var box = $(this).data('status_box');
  box.checked = !box.checked;
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/br86rjby/8/)